# How to avoid "Arrow function expect to return a value" error in Airbnb ESLint

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, eslint-config-airbnb

I am running eslint and it is recommended to return a value whenever an arrow function(lambda function) is used. Well that makes sense. However, I come across a case that is hard to walk around.

```
Dict = {}
Instances = [/* an array of items where items is a dictionary that contains data */]
Instances.map((item) => {
      Dict[item.name] = item.url;
});
```

My goal is to get the data from the Instances array and fill the dictionary Dict with it. I am using the array function to assign key value pair to the dictionary, but that violates the rule of the arrow function.

Is there any iteratools or functions other than map that would help me to achieve the goal, and avoid the rule violation?

Comment: `Instances.map((item) => ( Dict[item.name] = item.url))` will return an array of `Dict[item.name]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** This **does not** adhere to [Airbnb's ES6 Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript).

---

> My goal is to get the data from the Instances array and fill the dictionary with it.

### Use [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

.. and just pass an empty object as the accumulator, filling it up as you iterate through your array.

```js
const instances = [
 { name: 'foo', url: 'https://google.com' }, 
 { name: 'bar', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com' }
]

const result = instances.reduce((dict, item) => {
  dict[item.name] = item.url

  return dict
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

#### Why not [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

`Array.map` always returns a new `Array` and is meant for mapping each array element to another format.

If your resulting data structure shouldn't be an `Array`, with the same length as the `Array` you are operating on, you should avoid using it.

#### Why [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)?

I use `forEach` only for doing "work" rather than transforming data. Transforming data is almost always achievable with just `map` and/or `reduce`.

Here's what I mean by "work":

```
const users = [userInstance, userInstance, userInstance]
users.forEach(user => user.sendEmail('Hello World'))
```

Comment: Tried that, but eslint gives another error/warning: [eslint] Assignment to property of function parameter 'dict'. (no-param-reassign).

Comment: The forEach code works. I assume the eslint treat forEach and reduce differently.

Comment: Sure it does and it can pass linting with no warnings, it's just not absolutely ideal for what you want to do.

Comment: Wait it **doesn't pass** linting? Wow, that really is a [debatable](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/719) rule in Airbnb's ESLint. You are right; As-is `reduce`. won't work. I find this rule kinda stupid and I'd personally drop that Style Guide if I had the chance, just for this.  But I guess a Code Style Guide is what it is.

Comment: I am wondering if efficiency matters in this case. Would using reduce be faster than forEach? Any suggestions on comparing the efficiency of a code snippet is welcomed.

Comment: `.reduce` shouldn't have significant performance differences than `.map`. Both iterate over an Array. It's just more semantically correct to use `reduce` for your use case since you are looking to *reduce* your Array to an Object.

Comment: Best not to mutate memory but return a new array

Comment: @dman Why do you think this code snippet mutates the original array?

Comment: @NikKyriakides my apologies, I thought it did but I was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Use `forEach` instead of `map`.

The point of `map` is to modify each item in an array and put the modified versions in a new array.

`forEach` just runs a function on each item.

Comment: Good point. forEach works in this case, and no linting issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ES6 solution to fill dictionary object this could help and should pass ESLint also:-

```
const dict = Instances.reduce((map, obj) => (map[obj.name] = obj.url, map), {});
```

**update**

```
const dict = Instances.reduce((map, obj) => {
  let mapClone = {};
  mapClone = Object.assign({}, map);
  mapClone[obj.name] = obj.url;
  return mapClone;
}, {});
```

Comment: This code is a bit hard for me to read. And the eslint has another error: Unexpected use of comma operator  no-sequences

Comment: I see could you try something like this?

`const dict = Instances.reduce((map, obj) => {
  let mapClone = {};
  mapClone = Object.assign({}, map);
  mapClone[obj.name] = obj.url;
  return mapClone;
}, {});`